# jQuery's data() method is not listing all data-attributes

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have the following DOM object:

```
> this
<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"datafieldchk" data-collection=​"collection_name" 
data-column-id=​"rds_issuer" data-company-default=​"true" 
data-display-name=​"Issuer ID" data-physical-name=​"ISSR_ID">​
```

But, when I try to grab all the data into an array using jQuery (1.10.2), the collection value is missing.

```
> $(this).data()
Object {columnId: "rds_issuer", companyDefault: true, displayName: "Issuer ID", 
physicalName: "ISSR_ID"}
```

Accessing the property directly works fine:

```
> $(this).data("collection")
rds_issuer_inc
```

All of the properties are set directly on the object before page load, there's no jQuery manipulation or anything like that going on, it just doesn't like to get all of my properties.

Comment: More code is needed, because accessing the element works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7qptp/

Comment: Which browser (console) are you using? I did a quick test in Firefox (Aurora) with both jQ1.10.2 and jQ1.11.0 - and the console shows all data values correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried changing lorenzo's jsfiddle with jquery 1.10.2 both uncompressed and minified and i've had no issues either. since accessing the property directly works, i would try testing this the same way the fiddle does - by displaying it on your ui instead of the console.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. It does work as intended. The issue has disappeared, and I may never know what the actual cause was.